# Unable to launch to FF-57 (Quantum) with WebdDriver 3.7.1

Tags: selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, firefox-quantum

This is my test set up -

`FF Quantum 57.0 (64-bit), geckodriver-v0.19.1, Ubuntu 14.10, Webdriver 3.7.1`

Test -

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path to geckodriver");
WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
webDriver.get("http://www.google.com/");
```

and this is the error I get -

```
/home/tarun/GG_SeleniumNew/src/main/resources/geckodriver: 1: /home/tarun/GG_SeleniumNew/src/main/resources/geckodriver: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The driver server has unexpectedly died!
Build info: version: '3.7.1', revision: '8a0099a', time: '2017-11-06T21:01:39.354Z'
System info: host: 'tarun-Vostro-2420', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.16.0-25-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:89)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:600)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:98)
at com.gg.core.SelTestCase.startDriver(SelTestCase.java:124)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:514)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:215)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:589)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:32510 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:138)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:314)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:357)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:218)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:194)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:85)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:186)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:138)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:86)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:101)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
at     org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
... 31 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:72)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:118)
... 46 more
```

Did I miss any configuration?

**Updates**
I tried same with FF 56.0.2 and yet encountered same issue

Answer (score 0):

I was using wrong gecko driver and not the one for linux. Problem solved.